# Immitate PHP 5.3 DateTime in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.2

I was playing with the DateTime object in PHP 5.3 on my local machine and made something useful but my host (NFS) is only running 5.2 and doesn't plan to upgrade until 5.3.1 is out.

So my question is, is this code possible using 5.2?
Specifically, DateTime::getTimestamp doesn't exist in 5.2

The nicetime.php include is similar to the one here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#89415 basically it just outputs how long until/ago a timestamp is)
<?php

```
include('include/nicetime.php');

if(isset($_GET['hour']) && isset($_GET['min']) && isset($_GET['AP']) && isset($_GET['TZ'])){
    if($_GET['AP'] == 'PM'){
        $reqHour = $_GET['hour']+12;
    }else{
        $reqHour = $_GET['hour'];
    }

    $reqHour = ($_GET['AP'] == 'PM' ? $_GET['hour']+12 : $_GET['hour']);
    $reqMin = ($_GET['min'] == 0 ? '00': $_GET['min']);
    
    date_default_timezone_set($_GET['TZ']); 
    $reqDate = date_create($reqHour.':'.$reqMin);

    echo '<h3>'.nicetime($reqDate->getTimestamp()).'</h3>';
}

?>
```

If you're wondering what the point of it is, a user wants to know how long until a certain time in a timezone different than they are in. Eg, when is it 9PM in England? 2 hours from now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last line would have to be translated to

```
echo '<h3>' . $reqDate->format('U') . '</h3>';
```

in order to work with PHP 5.2. Other that that, it looks fine.

**Edit:**
You could subclass `DateTime` to provide a forwards compatible solution:

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
    public function getTimestamp() {
         return method_exists('DateTime', 'getTimestamp') ? 
             parent::getTimestamp() : $this->format('U');
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh perfect, I didn't realise I could use format to get the timestamp! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complete DateTime 5.2 extension.  Look for my comment for setTimestamp to fix your time_zone issues though

https://gist.github.com/SeanJA/349273